# How does cryptochrome produce quantum entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, biology

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jepgOQEvWT0) video on the net, which explains how a bird called "European robin" uses a trick based on quantum entanglement to see the earth's magnetic field. I am just asking if some of you know any research paper or reference on this subject.

What I want to know is how exactly the molecule [Cryptochrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptochrome) in the bird's eye produces quantum entanglement after being hit by a photon.

Comment: I found these: http://www.physics.uci.edu/~tritz/Publications/RITZ2004.pdf and http://www.cell.com/biophysj/abstract/S0006-3495(09)00468-8 googling "quantum entanglement robin", so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @jinawee Thanks, but I would like to see papers which study how the chryptochrome produces quantum entanglement. The papers you gave don't even talk about the quantum physic aspect of the phenomena. I will refine my question.

Comment: If you know Spanish, this mentions several sources and seems to be skeptical about it: http://naukas.com/2011/07/25/un-computador-cuantico-en-el-ojo-del-petirrojo/. But I don't know nothing about it. I guess you already saw: http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/7/Suppl_2/S147.full

Comment: @jinawee I don't understand spanish, but this spanish paper cited intersting papers in english:http://sciencefocus.com/oup/oup-story/quantum-computers-have-birds-got-there-first

Comment: http://sciencefocus.com/oup/oup-story/quantum-computers-have-birds-got-there-first

Comment: and also this http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.040503